# How to make snap auto-update without delay?

Tags: snap

Under `apt`, the update process for an app like Firefox goes like this:

1. Run `apt upgrade`
2. Firefox complains that it needs to restart the next time you go somewhere.
3. Restart Firefox

Under `snap`, the process either proceeds like:

1. Get a notification that the app needs to be closed
2. Manually close all instances of Firefox
3. Run `snap refresh`
4. Reopen Firefox

Or like:

1. Continue to dismiss notifications that an update is available
2. Finally, snap gives up and applies the update even though the application is running
3. (I forget whether Firefox complains in this case or you just need to restart it to get the update.)

What I would like is for snap to instantly jump to updating the app in the background, even if it is already running, since Firefox can clearly tolerate being updated while it's running. Is this possible?

Comment: "Firefox can clearly tolerate being updated while it's running" No it does not, the application will update when you restart it. Snaps update every 4 times a day by default.

Comment: VTC: This behavior is due to a long-known bug [LP#1616650](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapd/+bug/1616650). Turns out that it's harder to fix than first appears, and engineers are still working on it. Code contributions to fix the bug are welcome, but those should be on the bug report, not here.

Comment: @UtkarshChandraSrivastava My point still stands, with apt you could update it while it is running and there would be no negative consequences aside from having to restart it once the update finished.

Comment: @user535733 Makes sense, unfortunate that that exists. If you write an answer saying why it's not possible at the moment I'll accept it.